# Question on Coordenate Base of a Infinite Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a infinite dimensional Banach space. If $\mathcal{B}=\{e_i:i\in I\}$ is a Hamel base for $X$. How to show that only a finite number of the coordinate functionals $e^{*}_i$ will be continuous.

---

My approach: Suppose that there is a $I_0\subseteq I$ infinite such that, for each $i\in I_0$,  $e^*_i$ is continuous. Then, there exists a countable infinite number of $i\in I_0$  such that $e^*_i$ is continuous. But having trouble to derive an absurd from this fact.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79184/at-most-finitely-many-hamel-coordinate-functionals-are-continuous-different).

Comment: @DavidMitra, why don't you post this as answer?

Comment: @Norbert I suppose we should just close this.

Comment: @DavidMitra, ok