# How to prove that for a Hamel basis in a infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ there exists one coordinate functional which is discontinuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let {$e_{\alpha}$} be a Hamel basis of $X$, which is a infinite dimensional Banach space, i.e., every vectoe can be represented as $$x=\sum_{finite} f_{\alpha}(x)e_{\alpha}$$
Show that the functionals $f_{\alpha}:X \to K$ are linear. Show that at least one of them is discontinuous.

I really don't know what to do since $f_{\alpha}$ does not need to be the coordinate functionals, does it? And I have a index set, say $\Omega$ which does not need countable so I don't know how to start.

Comment: It seems to me that by definition, $f_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th coordinate.  I don't know what you mean when you say it does not need to be the coordinate functional.

Comment: You can do better. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79184/at-most-finitely-many-hamel-coordinate-functionals-are-continuous-different?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I mean that I didn't know if indeed it is the $\alpha$th coordinate functional.

Comment: David Mitra, I have seen that but there the set of indeces is countable and here it is not. I don't know how to use the argument in your link above.

Comment: @IreneGil The linked question does not assume anything of the sort. In fact, a Hamel basis for an infinite-dimensional Banach space is uncountable or finite. What the question does is assume there are infinitely many coordinate functions that are continuous (perhaps uncountably many), and then take a countable subset of these to form a (countable) sum of vectors that produces a contradiction.