# Finite continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ a Banach space with $dim(E)=\infty$ and $B=\{x_{i} \ : \ i\in I\}$ algebraic basis of $E.$ Show that there is at most a finite number of functionals $x^{*}_{i}$ are continuous.

Well, to start with, I already have that $I$ is non-countable and I think we should use Baire's Theorem. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: You're on a Banach space, right? I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79184/at-most-finitely-many-hamel-coordinate-functionals-are-continuous-different) may be of assistance to you. You can read the answer by the user tree detective as well. Let me know if this post is helpful . For reference , I found it by searching "finitely many continuous functionals in a Hamel basis" on Google, and lo and behold this post was the first result!

Comment: Thank you!! @TeresaLisbon

Comment: You are welcome!