Injectivity of the canonical map to the double dual
Let $V$ be an arbitrary vector space (possibly infinite-dimensional) and $V^{**}$ be its double dual. Define
$$J: V \rightarrow V^{**}\\
\hspace{8mm} x \rightarrow \phi(x),$$
where $\phi(x): V^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\phi(x)(f) = f(x)$. I want to show $J$ is injective. Most discussions I've seen about this, e.g. this one, I kept seeing the same thing being said: "use the Hahn-Banach Theorem". I honestly did not know about his theorem until very recently, and I do not know exactly how to apply it in this situation. I was wondering, why is the existence of a Hamel basis for vector spaces not used instead? If we have
$$\phi(x)(f) = \phi(y)(f),\forall f \in V^{*},$$
then, by applying the projections to the equality above, $x$ and $y$ must have the same representation in the given basis, no? We would then be able to conclude that $x=y$.

Your argument is correct! You use Hahn-Banach to show the analogous result for continuous double-duals of locally convex topological vector spaces.

Your argument is correct, and Hahn-Banach is not really relevant in this context.
The injectivity of $\phi$ is equivalent to the claim that, for any nonzero $v \in V$, there is some $f \in V^*$ such that $f(v) \neq 0$.
For ordinary vector spaces, you do exactly what you said: pick a basis $B$ for $V$, and let $f_b \in V^*$ be the coordinate functional of each $b \in B$. Given $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$, there is some $b \in B$ such that $f_b(v) \neq 0$, and we are done.

The proof needs to change in the context of functional analysis, where we deal with topological vector spaces and continuous linear maps. Now, given some nonzero $v \in V$, we need to find a continuous functional $f \in V^*$ such that $f(v) \neq 0$. Unfortunately, the coordinate functionals of a Hamel basis are rarely continuous!
Hahn-Banach is a useful tool here: for normed spaces, for example, it tells us that any continuous functional on a subspace of $V$ can always be extended to some continuous functional defined on all of $V$.
So, we start with a nonzero functional $f_0$ on $\operatorname{span}\{v\}$, e.g. the unique functional sending $v$ to $1$. All functionals on finite-dimensional topological vector spaces are continuous (this is not obvious, but it is true!), so $f_0$ is continuous. Now, by Hahn-Banach, there exists some continuous functional $f$ on $V$ extending $f_0$; in particular, we have $f(v) = f_0(v) = 1 \neq 0$. Done!

Thank you! That clarified some misunderstandings I had. One more question though: you said that coordinate functionals of a Hamel basis are rarely continuous, but in normed vector spaces, continuity is equivalent to being bounded. Are they not bounded? I thought, intuitively, that they would have to be bounded.

Indeed, in normed spaces, coordinate functionals of a Hamel bases are rarely bounded. I agree it does seem kind of unintuitive! See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79184/19006 for a proof that at most finitely many coordinate functionals are continuous on a Banach space.
