# Bounded Linear Functional Extension Theorem for finite dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I am following the the book "Lecture notes on functional analysis". The following extension thm has been proven in the book.
[image]

If we consider the finite dimensional case of the $X$, does the following prove work for the existence of the linear functional $F$? $\to$ My guess is yes but I have some problem of proving the property $\|F\|=\|f\|$.

Let $\{x_1,\dots, x_k\}$ be basis for $V$. We can extend it to a basis  $\{x_1,\dots, x_k,x_{k+1},\dots , x_n\}$ of $X$ and set $F(x_m)=0$ for $m = k+1, \dots , n$. So for any $X\ni x = a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n$ , we can define $F(x)=a_1f(x_1)+\dots+a_kf(x_k)$. Then $F$ is a linear functional on $X$, $F(x)=f(x) , \forall x\in V$, and $\|F\|=\|f\|$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060848/hahn-banach-proof-by-extension-of-basis

Comment: I found this http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/928/Hahn_Banach_Theorem.html but the example is not clear to me.

Comment: can the following also be considered to show.
I think we do can have such an extension $F$ but the thing is that it would necessarily make $\|F\|$ comparable to $\|f\|$. 

$$|F(x)| =  |\sum_{i=1}^{k} \alpha_i f(x_i)| \le  \sum_{i=1}^{k} |\alpha_i f(x_i) | \le \|\alpha\| |\sum_{i=1}^{k} | f(x_i)||$$

$\|\alpha\|$ still could be large even if $\|x\|$ is small.

Comment: Yes, as well as the link I added after the comment.