# Convergent sequence such that its components doesn't converge to the components of the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

I would like to find

- a vector space $E$
- a norm on $E$
- a sequence $(u_n)$ which converges for this norm but such that its components doesn't converge to the component of the limit.

---

First $E$ should be infinite dimensional.

Second I am tying to look at $E=\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Take $u_n=(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{\text{n zeros}},1/n,1/(n+1),\ldots,1/(n+p),\ldots)$.

or

$u_n=(1/1,1/2,\ldots,1/n,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$.

We have $||u_n||_1=\sum_{k=1}^n1/k$

Comment: The question does not make much sense. Please specify the space of sequences you are considering and specify the norm you want to use.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33287/8157) can be an answer, if I understand the question properly.